# Prevent infinite loop issue in php

Tags: php, while-loop

I am working on a project and I have two portions of code:

**Wish.class.php**

```html
public function getWishes(){
        return $this->database->query('SELECT * FROM wishes');
    }
```

**index.php**

```html
<?php
        while ($wishes = $wish->getWishes()->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2><?=$wishes->title;?></h2>
                    <p><?=$wishes->wish;?></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

When I run `ìndex.php`, I am able to get `$wishes->title` and `$wishes->wish`. The `var_dump($wishes)` fives me the following result:
[image: Var_dump]

The problem I am facing is that, on the `index.php` the `while` generate an infinite loop and I don't really know why. Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: The `query()` and the `fetch()` methods are implemented by you? If so, what does  `fetch` contains?

Comment: only implemented `query`, the `fetch()` I am using he is the one provided by `pdo`

Comment: Save into a variable this part: `$wish->getWishes()` and then in the while loop use `$whishes = $variable->fetch()`

Comment: Because, you are calling the function in while condition and it true always after every execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Please replace your code in index.php (Line no. 34 to 49) with below code.

```
<?php
    $wishes = $wish->getWishes()->fetchAll();
    foreach ($wishes as $wish) {
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2><?= $wish->title; ?></h2>
                <p><?= $wish->wish; ?></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?
    }
    ?>
```

Please let me know if it works for you.